# Changing font size for only one jquery ui autocomplete input

Tags: jquery-ui, styles, jquery-ui-autocomplete

So i have three input boxes with jquery ui autocomplete, and i want to change the font size to smaller for two of them.
Tried something like this but it didn`t work:

```
$($('.ui-autocomplete-input')[1]).find('.ui-menu-item').find('.ui-corner-all').css('font-size','12px');
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it by changing the way that the list is rendered and add a class to either the `li` and/or the `a`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheJoeFletch/Q55Gj/1/)

```
$("#input1").autocomplete({
    delay: 0,
    minLength: 0,
    source: ["One", "Two", "Three"]
}).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $("<li class=\"li-class\"></li>")//added list class here
       .data("item.autocomplete", item)
       .append("<a class=\"a-class\">" + item.label + "</a>") //added the anchor class here.
       .appendTo(ul);
};​
```